# Merging three categorical / factor variables in R

Tags: r, variables, merge, categorical-data

I have three categorical variables to a question about climate change action. There are three levels of responses that people can take: "No, I'm not going to do that", "yes, I would be willing to do that", and "Hey, I'm already doing it, mate!". I would like to merge the three responses, so that I have just one climate change action variable. I've converted the responses to numeric. So I have:

```
x=c(1,2,1,NA,NA)
y=c(2,1,3,1,NA)
z=c(2,NA,3,2,NA)
```

what I would like to create is a third variable, 'a'

```
  x  y  z  a
  1  2  2  2
  2  1 NA  2
  1  3  3  3
 NA  1  2  2
 NA NA NA NA
```

'a' would take the highest value of the corresponding value of x, y or z. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmax`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(x, y, z) %>%
     mutate(a = pmax(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      x     y     z     a
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     2     2
#2     2     1    NA     2
#3     1     3     3     3
#4    NA     1     2     2
#5    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

As we need all the columns, it can be simplified as

```
tibble(x, y, z) %>%
    mutate(a = pmax(!!! ., na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
cbind(x, y, z, a = pmax(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE))
```